# How can I include my image folder structure in my React App?

Tags: webpack

I hope you can help me.
When I run webpack my app gets built out into a dist folder.
[image]
Unfortunately the **img** folders don't get copied over so I end up with an app without images. What is the proper way to implement this through webpack or where is a good place to start? i've taken a look at the webpack documentation but am not sure where to look exactly.

webpack.config.js file below

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets:['env','react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }]
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
     { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' }
     // other loaders
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you
Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpack config file use `url-loader` in loader rules.
Inside your rules Just add one more rule for loading images:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192
        }
     } ]
 }
```

Also install `url-loader` npm package.

To install it:

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

It will install the url loader that can convert resolved paths of images as BASE64 strings.
If files having size less than **8192 byte** then image url will be returned otherwise if file size greater than **limit** then file will used directly via `file-loader`.
You may need to install 
file-loader as well.

To install it:

```
npm install file-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for that input. Is the syntax you provided missing closing `]` and `}` or is it correct as is?

Comment: that worked with the addition of the appropriate closing tags.

Comment: @Moe-Joe Oh yes indeed it was typo. Thanks for pointing out. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `file-loader` for loading image files with webpack. Just install it via npm and add it to the loaders and you should be good to go. You can find more info about this [in the webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images).

Good Luck

If, in this way, it does not make it difficult to put the images on the page, try to insert them with their paths to data.json and then use the map method in some const to show them all on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Image usage can be done using a dial pad, if a folder of images is placed in the Public folder in the reagent application, which would later be invoked by the application during the application development. The reason is that when you start using the npm start command, the public folder is placed on the port of 3000, localhost.